# im trying to fetch values from db but getting errors which say cmd,dr, doesnt exist in the current context

Tags: c#, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# having some errors from fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374968/c-having-some-errors-from-fetching)

```
public partial class BioreCottonPurchaseSlip2011 : Form
{

    Library obj = new Library();


    public BioreCottonPurchaseSlip2011()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    public void enableDisableControls(bool flag)
    {
        TxtExtensionNo.Enabled = flag;
        TxtFarmerCode.Enabled = flag;
        TxtFarmerName.Enabled = flag;
        TxtBasicPrice.Enabled = flag;
        TxtPremium.Enabled = flag;
        TxtWeight.Enabled = flag;
        TxtTotalAmountBasic.Enabled = flag;
        TxtTotalAmountPremium.Enabled = flag;
        TxtBalancePay.Enabled = flag;
        BtnSave.Enabled = flag;
        BtnCancel.Enabled = flag;

    }




    public void clearControls()
    {
        TxtExtensionNo.Text = "";
        TxtFarmerCode.Text = "";
        TxtFarmerName.Text = "";
        TxtBasicPrice.Text = "";
        TxtPremium.Text = "";
        TxtWeight.Text = "";
        TxtTotalAmountBasic.Text = "";
        TxtTotalAmountPremium.Text = "";
        TxtBalancePay.Text = "";


    }

    private void BtnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj.GetConnection() == true)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Connected !!!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Not connnected !!!";
        }
        enableDisableControls(true);
        BtnNew.Enabled = false;
        // lblError.Text = "";
        string connectionString = "Data Source=TANYA-PC;Initial Catalog=biore1;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM cottonpurchase";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        connection.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, "cottonpurchase");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "cottonpurchase";



    }

    private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj.GetConnection() == true)
        {

            //dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
            MessageBox.Show("insert into cottonpurchase values(" + TxtExtensionNo.Text + ",'" + monthCalendar1.TodayDate + "'," + TxtFarmerCode.Text + ",'" + TxtFarmerName.Text + "'," + TxtBasicPrice.Text + "," + TxtPremium.Text + "," + TxtWeight.Text + "," + TxtTotalAmountBasic.Text + "," + TxtTotalAmountPremium.Text + "," + TxtBalancePay.Text + ")");

            if (obj.ExecuteSQLStatement("insert into cottonpurchase values(" + TxtExtensionNo.Text + ",'" + monthCalendar1.TodayDate + "'," + TxtFarmerCode.Text + ",'" + TxtFarmerName.Text + "'," + TxtBasicPrice.Text + "," + TxtPremium.Text + "," + TxtWeight.Text + "," + TxtTotalAmountBasic.Text + "," + TxtTotalAmountPremium.Text + "," + TxtBalancePay.Text + " )") == true)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Item(s) Saved";
                clearControls();
                BtnSave.Enabled = false;
                BtnNew.Enabled = true;
                enableDisableControls(false);
            }

            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Item(s) Not Saved";
            }
        }


        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Connection Error. Please contact your administrator.";
        }




        enableDisableControls(false);
        clearControls();
        BtnNew.Enabled = true;

        try
        {
            //double getvat = 0;
            //double calculatevat = 0;
            //getvat = Convert.ToDouble(TxtTotalAmountBasic.Text);
            //calculatevat = getvat * 0.18;
            //TxtBasicPrice.Text = calculatevat.ToString();
            //TxtBasicPrice.Enabled = false;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            // lblError.Text = "Please contact your administrator. (Error - TARS0001DATMIS)";
            clearControls();
            enableDisableControls(false);
            BtnNew.Enabled = true;
            //lblInvoiceNo.Text = "INVOIC NO";
        }
    }


    private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enableDisableControls(false);
        clearControls();
        BtnNew.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TxtFarmerCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection("Data Source=TANYA-PC;Initial Catalog=biore1;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select farmername, from cottonpurchase where farmercode=@aa", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@aa", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TxtFarmerCode.Text;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows == false)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                // textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString(); Since U r going to give the ID and retrieve in textBox1.
                TxtFarmerName.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                //textBox3.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                //textBox4.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                //textBox7.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                //dateTimePicker1.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                //dateTimePicker2.Text = dr[5].ToString();
                //textBox5.Text = dr[6].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        //    lblError = "THE GIVEN ID IS UNAVAILABLE";
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Repost of [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374968/please-help-having-some-errors-from-fetching-it-says-that-conn-and-cmd-and-dr-d)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your variable types

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(...);
SqlReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME OUT ITS NOT FETCHING ANYTHING

Comment: Try removing the , from the "Select farmername, from conntonpurchase ..." statement

Comment: is there any data in the tables to get?  You may want to change your adding of parameters to something like SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@aa", SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value = TxtFarmerCode.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

Comment: yes i do have values> is it correct to do it in the textchanged event?

Answer (score 0):

In `TxtFarmerCode_TextChanged`, you haven't defined the variables `cmd` or `dr`.

You'll want something like this:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select farmername, from cottonpurchase where farmercode=@aa", conn);
        [...]
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: thaanx that worked but still there is an error for dr.hasrows

Comment: you'll likely want `SqlDataReader` instead - updated answer to reflect that.  Please bear in mind, this site is not here to teach you how to program; there are plenty of other resources for that.

Comment: WHY DOESNT IT FETCH ANY VALUES FROM THE DATABASE ? PLEASE HELP MEE????